# Is it possible to make a single login of two joomla project?

Tags: php, joomla

I am new to joomla. I have two joomla project now my work is too make this two joomla project access in a single login location or either any of the project.  If a logged in a single project i am going to access another project without login.  Whether it is possible?  If possible please guide me how can it will do?

Comment: Your question is too ambiguous - are you wanting to be able to login on one site and be logged in on another site at the same time? Or are you just wanting to share a single table of users between two sites with separate logins for each?

Comment: I am having two joomla project with two separate database.  My task is, if one user logged in x project then i opened the y joomla project.  It will provide the result of already login status.   This is the required i have.   Give any idea for this.

Answer (score 2):

There is no good way to do this. Without sharing the user and session tables between the two sites there isn't a way for the second site to be able to tell automatically who a random visitor is based upon the first site.

I would suggest [Community ACL](http://www.corephp.com/community-acl/community-acl-for-joomla-1.5.html) - I've never used the feature personally but it has multi-site user synchronization that might suit your needs. However, I would like to go on record saying that there is probably a more security conscious way of fulfilling your client's requirements, though without knowing excactly what you're trying to accomplish I can't say how. Sharing login data between two sites like this is never good.